# S2S network topology across multiple partners

Tags: salesforce2salesforce

We're creating a network of non profits that all provide the same service across overlapping geographical areas.

I'd like to set this up so that each non profit has its own org and shares the common data with its peers using Salesforce to Salesforce.

The questions is - with a bunch of orgs sharing the common data - how should we structure the S2S network?  I'm guessing hub and spoke but I'm afraid of hidden gotchas.

What are your thoughts?